# Set label text from different from class file

Tags: objective-c

What I would like the code to do is so when the button is pressed it runs the function in the Label.m file and it then sets the labels text to "test". Whenever I run it the code calls the function but doesn't change the labels text. Can someone please help me fix my code or show me the correct and easiest way to change a labels text from a class file.

In my FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *test;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *test;
```

In my FirstViewController.m

```
#import "Label.h"
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender {
    [Label getSchedule];
}
```

In my Label.h

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@interface Label : NSObject
+ (void)getSchedule;


@end
```

In my Label.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation Label

+ (void)getSchedule{
    NSLog(@"log");
    FirstViewController *VC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    VC.test.text = @"test";

}


@end
```

Comment: You are messaging a class method, not a method on the instance in your view.

Comment: At the time you call `VC.test.text`, the view controller's label hasn't been created yet. You need to set the label's text after the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As Maddy mentioned in the comments the original posters code would have worked if it was just called after the viewController had gotten all of its view objects. The easy way to achieve what the original poster wanted would be to simply add:

```
self.test.text = @"test";
```

to the viewControllers viewDidLoad method.

I'll leave my original answer here anyway, as I believe it improves on the original posters code and removes some of its dependencies. It still is way too complicated for what it wants to achieve but the pattern as such could be transferred to more befitting scenarios:

---

To elaborate on my comment:

Your method

```
+ (void)getSchedule{
    NSLog(@"log");
    FirstViewController *VC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    VC.test.text = @"test";
}
```

Is a class method. So, naturally it is fired, but your UILabel instance test this instance have no idea about this. Furthermore you seem to have created your own class Label which subclasses NSObject, but the actual label instance is a regular UILabel.

I would guess what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
@interface Label : UILabel
- (void)getSchedule;
@end
```

...

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Label *test;
```

Edit: forgot the method(!)

```
- (void)getSchedule{
    self.text = @"test";
}
```

And finally in your viewController...

```
#import "Label.h"
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender {
    [self.test getSchedule];
}
```

Comment: There is nothing (technically) wrong with the use of the class method in the posted code.

Comment: Im very new to Objective-c and I appreciate your answer. But is there an easier way that I can change the text that the label says in FirstViewController via the Label class?

Comment: @maddy Looking at it again, I see that you're right. It is however extremely convoluted and it is very hard to see why Label needs to know about the VC at all.

Comment: @user1953754 `self.test.text = @"test";` in your VC should actually be sufficient.